# Smallest area of triangle

Tags: optimization, analytic-geometry, triangles, area

> Let $$f(x) = 3x^3 - 3x^2 +x - 1/9$$
>   For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let $l$ be the tangent line to the graph of
>   $f$ at the point $(a, f(a))$, and let $M$ and $N$ be the $x$- and $y$-intercepts of $l$ respectively.
>   Let $O$ be the origin.
>
> Find the point(s) $(a,f(a))$ so that triangle $\triangle OMN$ has the smallest area.

Hi, I'm wondering if the area of a triangle in a graph can be zero? 
I obtained three values of a such that two values of a gives zero while the other is a positive value (1/128)

Since the question wants smallest area (i.e minimum area), does that mean I should choose those two values of a?

Thank you.

Comment: I would go with the two values of $a$ that give zero area. It's not clear what your interest is in the third value; there are infinitely many such values. My guess would be you were trying to find a minimum by setting a derivative to zero and you found a local maximum. If we had any interest in positive areas I would suggest you show your work, but unless you want the other two values checked I think you have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)=3(x-1/3)^3$ and $f'(x)=9(x-1/3)^2$. Therefore $f(1/3)=f'(1/3)=0$and the tangent line $y=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$ for $a=1/3$ is $y=0$.

It follows that for $a=1/3$ the points $M,N,0$ are along the same line and the triangle $\triangle OMN$ has area zero.

More generally,
$$M=((6a+1)/9,0)\quad\text{and}\quad N=(0,-(6a+1)(3a-1)^2/9).$$
and therefore 
$$|\triangle OMN|= 2(a+1/6)^2(a-1/3)^2.$$
It follows that the minimum area is attained at $a=1/3$ and $a=-1/6$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the question is about the area of a triangle so, if one or two of your tangent lines go through the origin then there is no triangle.

I would specify the values of $(a) $ where the tangent line passes through the origin and the values where we actually get a triangle.

The real problem is that the area is a continuous function of $(a)$ and the minimum area of zero is attained where $$f(a)=af'(a)$$

That is at $a=1/3$ and at $a=-1/6$ thus there is no positive minimum area.